# How to clear permgen memory space

Tags: java, exception, memory, out-of-memory

I am using MAT to analyze memory.

`Size: 14.4 MB Classes: 7k Objects: 350.9k Class Loader: 116`

I've got the above report using MAT memory analyzer. But I can't find any way to clear those classes, objects.
Is there any way to remove all those object and clean permgen memory.
Can we clean permgen memory or I have to increase `xms, xmx and launcher.XXMaxPermSize` size in `eclipse.ini` file and make sure all object are nullify after use.

Comment: The prefix `perm` should be an indication that it is permanent. In Java 7 and before you would have to restart the process. I believe in Java 8 they dealing with this differently.

Comment: @leppie means i can't clear premgem memory. All those classes, objects and class loader are going to be there for ever. Right now i am using jdk 7 if i update to jdk 8 is there any way to clean it.

Comment: I dont know how java 8 deals with it. But I have the same problem doing hot deployments on Tomcat with java 7. Unfortunately the version of Tomcat we use, does not work reliably on java 8, so I have not tested it. For my dev machine, I just increased the max perm size to a few gigabytes. No such luxury on the other servers.

Comment: In short currently there is no way to clear it. I can only increase premgen memory.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no function that clears permgen. On default, jvm holds all the loaded classes indefinitely. But you can change this behaviour using -`XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled` and -`XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC` parameters.

If you use `CMSClassUnloadingEnabled` parameter the GC will also sweep PermGen and remove classes which are no longer used.

Comment: can you guide me  how to use it.

Comment: @PraveenGaikwad usage is same as other jvm parameters. You can give them alongside with MaxPermSize. Like `... -Xmx512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC`